# Django admin filter fields on foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

Within my django project I have a couple of models that relate to each other via a FK.

```
School
---
id
name

Account
---
id
user_id
school_id
status
```

Within the django admin site I'm trying to filter the Account page to only show accounts that have the same school id as the staff user viewing the site.

```
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'status', email, 'get_school', 'created')
    search_fields = ('user__username', )
    list_filter = ('status',)

    def get_school(self, obj):
        return obj.school.name

    get_school.short_description = 'School'

    # Display all if superuser, otherwise only show same school accounts
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(AccountAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs

        return qs.filter(school_id=2)
```

As you can see I've managed to get it to filter correctly if I hard code the school_id in there. However, I'm struggling to get the current staff users school id. I've confused myself to no end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to get the Account from the user context, which you can then filter on:

```
account = Account.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)

return qs.filter(school_id=account.school_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you'll need to import the model too.

For example:

```
from <application_name>.models import <model_name>
```